# Amplifier in cardiac pulse meter

Tags: amplifier, filter

I don't speak English very well so sorry for the problems in the language.

I am working on a cardiac pulse meter, it is based on the changes of the flux in the blood that go through the fingers. The part of the solution that i have at the moment is a transducer and then a low pass filter (cutting frequency of 15 Hz). The operation range of the circuit is from 0.8 Hz to 3 Hz because that is the frequency of the hearthbeat. I need to amplify my signal so i wanted to add a OPAMP UA741 as an amplifier but it didn't work. The signal is really weak and after the OPAMP the signal dies.

Here a picture of the signal after the low pass filter.

[image: Photo of the oscilloscope]
Here a picture of the circuit diagram. Consider that model OPAMP is not TL081, it is UA741. Also, the resistence called LDR is actually a light-dependent resistor that can have a resistance from 0 to 5k.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fdL5dk.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I have updated the resistances and capacity values, also i have added a capacitor in order to block the DC component of the signal. When i measure the voltage with the osciloscope at DC coupling in the Vout point what i read is a DC signal that moves from 0 to 20 mV with the shape expected of the hearthbeat. Now what i need to do is amplify the signal from that range to 2 V, but when i try to add an non-inversor amplifier OPAMP with gain of 10 (for example) my signal after the opamp dies. This is my first electronic proyect, i am trying to learn whit this so i will be very grateful for any help. Thanks.

Comment: Show a circuit diagram of your amplifier including input sensors and power supplies and note that the 741 is usually a very poor choice of device for most op-amp applications. [Read this about it](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/304521/reasons-not-to-use-a-741-op-amp/304522#304522).

Comment: Hi! Welcome here. I fully agree with all that Andy said. Also, don't worry, your English is pretty good, and if we don't understand something, we'll tell you. What we don't understand currently is what circuit exactly you've built (and why you picked the antique 741).

Comment: i just added the circuit diagram. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Power supplies - connections and voltages? R1 value? C value? R0 value?

Comment: Please annotate your schematics with the values of the components, voltages,  and tell us what LDR you're using!

Comment: Are you really using a TL081?

Comment: Consider that LDRs can be very slow; yes, you're only interested in up to 3Hz, but (according to Wikipedia at least) they can take as long as a second to recover from light exposure; this limits you to less than 0.5Hz signals.

Comment: I have added the info needed, and actually i am using a UA741.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are confused about the **rate** of the heart beat and the **frequency** content of your signal. You are filtering at a frequency that is too low to pass the heart beat signal. Try filtering with a low-pass cutoff of 10Hz or 20Hz instead.

Generally, these kinds of devices (photoplethysmographs) use an infrared LED and an infrared phototransistor. A phototransistor will give a much faster response than an LDR.

BTW, you aren't really observing a change in the flux of the blood, I think the capillaries expand a bit with each heartbeat so the volume of blood through which the light passes will increase.

Comment: Thanks for the help, i have changed the low-pass cutoff from 3 Hz to 15 Hz and now the signal is a little stronger. I don't have access to an infrared LED and a infrared phototransistor but the response is faster enough to take the right shape of the hearthbeath (i mean the signal that i measure with the osciloscope). I just need to amplify the weak signal but i have problems with it that i can't solve, i have tried a lot of things but nothing works, any idea is well received.

Answer (score 0):

As @Elliot says, raise the LPF cutoff.

The heart beat has some FAST edges, perhaps 0.1 second edges. To fully preserve those shapes, aim for 0.05 second risetimes.

Thus your R*C product should be 0.05 second, or faster (smaller).